# Multiple UPDATES in MySQL are taking too long

Tags: mysql

I have multiple UPDATES that happen every time I loop through the code.  At the time of writing the question I have 80 separate UPDATES happening from the one table.

This is taking 10.8 seconds.  If I don't do the updates (only output them to the screen so I can see what the program is doing) it takes 2.7 seconds.  The 8 seconds is locking up the database for too long :(

An example of the UPDATEs are

```
UPDATE players SET energy=energy+14 WHERE playerID=243 LIMIT 1
UPDATE players SET energy=energy+7 WHERE playerID=258 LIMIT 1
UPDATE players SET energy=energy+3986 WHERE playerID=244 LIMIT 1
UPDATE players SET energy=energy+2990 WHERE playerID=245 LIMIT 1
```

Any ideas on how to speed this up?

Comment: Are you sure you need this in your database? Maybe you want a **memcached layer** in between, that stores quick-changing player-data like this. You can then store the memcached values on regular times (eg when a player logs off, or a major event happens)

Comment: If you do want the database: can you show us the entire output of `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` so we are sure it is an update that is blocking, not a select/insert? Can you show the `SHOW CREATE TABLE players` output so we can check datatypes and indexes?

Comment: Also make sure you are doing all the updates in one database connection.

Answer (score 2):

What is the benefit of the `LIMIT 1` clause?  Drop it.

Do you have an index on `playerID`?  If not, add one.

How big is the `Players` table?  How many rows?  How big is each row?

Have you considered a prepared UPDATE statement which parameterizes the operation:

```
UPDATE Players SET Energy = Energy + ? WHERE PlayerID = ?
```

You can then execute this multiple times with different parameters:

```
  14   243
   7   258
3986   244
2990   245
```

The advantage of using prepared statements is that the DBMS doesn't have to reparse the SQL each time, so it has less work to do.

Comment: The index and prepared sound good, but I don't understand what benefit dropping the `LIMIT 1` could have. At worst, it has no impact, at best, it causes an earlier return.

Comment: We don't have the schema of your table, but presumably the PlayerID is the primary key or has a unique constraint on it.  If so, then there is extra work involved in parsing LIMIT 1 (not a lot, but...) and it doesn't change the result.  If it isn't a unique column, then LIMIT 1 leads to your database being corrupted (since there could be different rows for the given PlayerID with different values for the Energy column.  Also, the LIMIT clause unnecessarily limits the portability of your SQL.

Comment: I have the following code now $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE players SET energy=:energy, confidence=:confidence, morale=:morale WHERE playerID=:playerID ");
    $stmt->bindParam(':energy', $energy);
     $stmt->bindParam(':confidence', $confidence);
     $stmt->bindParam(':morale', $morale);
     $stmt->bindParam(':playerID', $playerID);
    $playerID=1;  #The key is the players ID
$energy = 1000;
$confidence = 1100;
$morale = 1200;
$stmt->execute(); but this gives a Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Comment: The fatal error strongly suggests that $mysqli is not valid.  At this point, you're delving into another area, somewhat separate from the pure SQL question above.  However, I'm tolerably confident that you need to ensure your connection worked and created the $mysqli correctly.  Logically, your sequence of operations looks correct.  Are you using Perl + DBI?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to ensure that you do not have any indexes on the `energy` row of players, and ensure that you have an index on `playerID` (indexes decreases lookup times, but increases updates/inserts times).

Additionally, I suggest reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update-speed.html for some ideas.  One suggestion is to try locking the table, updating everything, then unlocking.  If you give me some more information on what version of MySQL you are running (and what kind of database/tables you are using (MyIsam/InnoDB, etc)), I might be able to help you further.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Do you mean 'indexes decrease lookup times'?

Comment: And 'increate updates/insert' too then I guess. @Chris probably switched them?